# Can Banshee play internet radio from .pls files?

Tags: banshee, internet-radio

I've recently become interested in Internet Radio, and have found a few stations that I would like to add in Banshee.

Examples are the stations shown at http://www.chronixradio.com/ - but the only one I can add in Banshee is the 'Metal Masters' one. I tried getting the URLs for all of them from 'Listen Now' -> one of the radios -> 'MP3 Streams' -> '128k Cable/DSL', but for some reason the only one that Banshee can figure out is the Metal Masters one.

I suspect that it may be because the other stations have 'mirrors' in the .pls files. Is Banshee incapable of handling that? Or is the problem something else?

Please help - it seems a lot of Internet Radio Stations use .pls files, and I would be surprised to learn that Banshee can't handle them.

Comment: See this question: http://askubuntu.com/q/42840/19053

Answer (score 5):

I'm using Banshee 2.2.0.

The only way i find to save a station is:

1. Go to Media>Open Location from the menu or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>
2. Select the .pls file you want to import and click 'Open'
3. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> on location of .pls file (with the file://....)
4. Click on Radio and Add Station
5. On URL location, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> the location of .pls file.
6. Station save :)

Answer (score 1):

From [banshee](http://banshee.fm/download/archives/1-2-0/) as of version 1.2:

```
Playlist Importing (.pls, .m3u)
Import your carefully created .m3u and .pls playlists.
```

So yes it can import .pls and mirrors are a normal part of a pls file.

Comment: ...then why can't I add the abovementioned radio stations in Banshee? They simply won't play in Banshee - only the one called 'Metal Masters' will

Comment: I can't find this option

Answer (score 1):

I also run Banshee (v 2.0.0) and im able to add individual URL's of internet radio's and play them but when I import a .pls playlist containing mirrors of streaming servers, it doesn't work.

The only way I have managed to play the radio stations from the playlist by opening the playlist as a location.

- Go to `Media` → `Open Location` from the menu or press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd>
- Select the *.pls* file you want to import and click `Open`

The station starts to play automatically but I haven't been able to save the playlist or even view from which server its currently streaming from. Oh I miss Amarok 1.4. It used to do this in its sleep.

Answer (score 1):

> YES, Banshee can play internet radio from .pls files !
>
> Maybe this will work for you as it just worked for me.
>
> > Open the *.pls file with a text editor and select one of the URL's written there.
> >
> > In my case, I downloaded a file called "list.pls" from sky.fm; I opened it with gedit and just copied in Banshee the first of sixteen URL's written there  (write the URL in "Stream URL" in "Add new radio station").
>
> It is working OK since I added it; I just double click the added radio station every time I want to listen the selected Internet radio station.
>
> :O)